Why is this script not opening trade in trading view strategy tester?
Here is the code, opens a trade when the difference between the 2 EMA\s is more than 45 pips. SL and TP are both 15 pips.
//@version=5
strategy("EMA Long Strategy", overlay=true)

// Define the moving averages
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

// Calculate the difference in pips
pips_difference = (ema50 - ema200) / syminfo.mintick

// Define the entry condition
long_condition = pips_difference > 45

// Define stop loss and take profit
stop_loss = close - 15 * syminfo.mintick
take_profit = close + 15 * syminfo.mintick

// Execute the trade
if (long_condition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=0.01, stop=stop_loss, limit=take_profit)

This should work, but it does not open any trades!
Tried to add strategy.exit, but to no avail

Try putting stop & limit in strategy.exit
and limit the number of candles for backtesting
Something like that:
//@version=5
strategy("EMA Long Strategy", overlay=true)

// Define the moving averages
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

// Calculate the difference in pips
pips_difference = (ema50 - ema200) / syminfo.mintick

// Define the entry condition
long_condition = pips_difference > 45

// Define stop loss and take profit
stop_loss = close - 15 * syminfo.mintick
take_profit = close + 15 * syminfo.mintick

// Execute the trade
if long_condition and bar_index > last_bar_index - 2000
    strategy.entry(
      "Long",
      strategy.long,
      qty   = 0.01)

if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(
      id         = 'Exit',
      from_entry = 'Long',
      stop       = stop_loss,
      limit      = take_profit)


Thanks Gustavo, however still not opening any trades. would you be able to copy paste it in trading view and try it ?- it's really driving me crazy as it should work....

Now I post full code. (look)[ https://www.tradingview.com/x/Dcc6az4r ]
